# How do you play animation in unity when you walk through a trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, virtual-reality

I’m making a horror vr game in unity with the ovr player controller and I’m trying to figure out how to make an animation I made in blender play behind me when ever I walk into a certain box trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something along the lines:

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject player;
[SerializeField] private Animation animation;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject == player)
        animation.Play();
}
```

The `player` and `animation` fields need to be initialized from the inspector.

Comment: Whenever i put that i get error cs0246 'The type or namespace name 'collision' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: It's a type in the answer and should be `Collision` (see [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html)) ... @ConnorFett please also think about what you are doing .. and try to not simply copy paste code from the internet but rather **understand** what you are doing ...